# How to use async-await with Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, async-await

At the moment I am using this code below to get the results of several Promises using async await:

```
let matchday = await createMatchday(2018, 21, [/*9 matches of matchday*/]);
//Further calculations

async function createMatchday(seasonNr, matchdayNr, matches) {
  let md = new Matchday(seasonNr, matchdayNr, matches);
  await md.getStandings(seasonNr, matchdayNr);
  return md;
}

class Matchday {
  constructor(seasonNr, matchdayNr, matches) {
    this.seasonNr = seasonNr;
    this.matchdayNr = matchdayNr;
    this.matches = matches;
  }

  async getStandings(seasonNr, matchdayNr) {
    let promiseArr = [];
    promiseArr.push(makeHttpRequestTo(`http://externService.com/standings?seasonNr=${seasonNr}&matchdayNr=${matchdayNr}`);
    promiseArr.push(makeHttpRequestTo(`http://externService.com/homestandings?seasonNr=${seasonNr}&matchdayNr=${matchdayNr}`));
    promiseArr.push(makeHttpRequestTo(`http://externService.com/awaystandings?seasonNr=${seasonNr}&matchdayNr=${matchdayNr}`));
    promiseArr.push(makeHttpRequestTo(`http://externService.com/formstandings?seasonNr=${seasonNr}&matchdayNr=${matchdayNr}`));

    let resulArr = await Promise.all(promiseArr);
    this.standings = resultArr[0];
    this.homeStandings = resultArr[1];
    this.awayStandings = resultArr[2];
    this.formStandings = resultArr[3];
  }
}

function makeHttpRequest(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //AJAX httpRequest to url
    resolve(httpRequest.responseText);
  }
}
```

Is this actually the best way to read the values of several promises where the promises don't need to wait for each other to end but rather work at the same time by using Promise.all() or is there a better way to make e.g. several httpRequests at the same time because this seems quite repetetive?

Comment: Your current code *does* make multiple requests at the same time (assuming the `Promise.resolve`s are replaced with something that makes a request)

Comment: I am just wondering if this is the way to write something like that because it seems quite unhandy...

Comment: What do you mean by _"better"_? What is the requirement?

Comment: Do you mean the code seems too repetitive? I agree, but without seeing the *real* code, it's hard to say what could be improved

Comment: Added "real" code...

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `Promise.all` there, for `resultArr`?

Comment: Yes my bad, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to wait for all requests to complete before continuing the execution flow, you could make the properties of the class be promises:

```
class Matchday {
  constructor(seasonNr, matchdayNr, matches) {
    this.seasonNr = seasonNr;
    this.matchdayNr = matchdayNr;
    this.matches = matches;
    ['standings', 'homeStandings', 'awayStandings', 'formStandings'].forEach(propertyName => {
      let url = `http://externService.com/${propertyName.toLowerCase()}`
        + `?seasonNr=${seasonNr}&matchdayNr=${matchdayNr}`
      this[propertyName] = makeHttpRequestTo(url)
    });
  }
}
```

### Test using the following snippet

```js
class Matchday {
  constructor(seasonNr, matchdayNr, matches) {
    this.seasonNr = seasonNr;
    this.matchdayNr = matchdayNr;
    this.matches = matches;
    ['standings', 'homeStandings', 'awayStandings', 'formStandings'].forEach(propertyName => {
      let url = `http://externService.com/${propertyName.toLowerCase()}`
        + `?seasonNr=${seasonNr}&matchdayNr=${matchdayNr}`
      this[propertyName] = makeHttpRequestTo(url)
    });
  }
}

/**************************************
 * Test harness
 **************************************/
 
function makeHttpRequestTo(url) {
  // Fake an AJAX httpRequest to url
  const requested_resource = url.match('^.*\/\/.*\/([^?]*)')[1];
  const fake_response_data = 'data for ' + url.match('^.*\/\/.*\/(.*)$')[1];
  let delay = 0;
  let response = '';
  switch (requested_resource) {
    // To make it interesting, let's give the 'standings' resource 
    // a much faster response time
    case 'standings':
      delay = 250;
      break;
    case 'homestandings':
      delay = 2000;
      break;
    case 'awaystandings':
      delay = 3000;
      break;
    case 'formstandings':
      delay = 4000; // <== Longest request is 4 seconds
      break;
    default:
      throw (util.format('Unexpected requested_resource: %s', requested_resource));
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(fake_response_data), delay);
  });
}

async function testAccessingAllProperties() {
  const testId = "Test accessing all properties";
  console.log('\n%s', testId);
  console.time(testId)
  let md = new Matchday(2018, 21, []);
  console.log(await md.standings);
  console.log(await md.homeStandings);
  console.log(await md.awayStandings);
  console.log(await md.formStandings);
  console.timeEnd(testId)
}

async function testAccessingOnlyOneProperty() {
  const testId = `Test accessing only one property`;
  console.log('\n%s', testId);
  console.time(testId)
  let md = new Matchday(2018, 21, []);
  console.log(await md.standings);
  console.timeEnd(testId)
}

async function all_tests() {
  await testAccessingAllProperties();
  await testAccessingOnlyOneProperty();
}

all_tests();
```

### Conclusion

The above snippet shows that the execution time is not penalized by properties that are not accessed. And execution time of accessing all properties is no worse than using `promise.all`.

You'd just need to remember to use `await` when accessing those properties.

Comment: Hey Robin, the answer is a bit late but makes way more sense than the others. Very enlightening, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Your URLs all follow the same sort of pattern, so you can greatly reduce your code by `map`ping an array of `['', 'home', 'away', 'form']` to the URLs. Then, `map` those URLs to Promises through `makeHttpRequestTo`, and then you can destructure the awaited results into the `this.` properties:

```
async getStandings(seasonNr, matchdayNr) {
  const urls = ['', 'home', 'away', 'form']
    .map(str => `http://externService.com/${str}standings?seasonNr=${seasonNr}&matchdayNr=${matchdayNr}`);
  const promiseArr = urls.map(makeHttpRequestTo);
  [
    this.standings,
    this.homeStandings,
    this.awayStandings,
    this.formStandings
  ] = await Promise.all(promiseArr);
}
```

To populate each property individually rather than waiting for all responses to come back:

```
async getStandings(seasonNr, matchdayNr) {
  ['', 'home', 'away', 'form']
    .forEach((str) => {
      const url = `http://externService.com/${str}standings?seasonNr=${seasonNr}&matchdayNr=${matchdayNr}`;
      makeHttpRequestTo(url)
        .then((resp) => {
          this[str + 'Standings'] = resp;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Think this should work and it looks not as repetetive :)

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to go, since each async action doesn't depend on the previous or later. This way we are waiting for a function to complete it's execution before moving to the other. Which is not required. This kind of makes it an async/await hell.

Comment: @AdeelImran The `Promise.all` means that each asynchronous call will go out at once, and will resolve once all responses come back. It's not waiting in serial, it's waiting in parallel.

Comment: Yes true, but in order to get result of lets say `Promise1` we have to wait until all `PromiseN`'s have been executed, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @IceRevenge See comments above - your current script's logic (and this one) populate the `this` properties once all requests come back, is that desirable, or do you actually need to put each response into `this.` as soon as the response comes back?

Comment: Adeel is right. In this case they can be handled all on their own. I still prefer CertainPerformance's way of writing the code. Adeel's code written nicer would be the better way to go.

Comment: That is what the OP has asked for, the most efficient way of doing it not the smallest one. As soon as you get value from `Promise1` you set it to i.e, `this.resultPromise1`, why wait for `PromiseN` to finish it's execution. Since the result that is being set to `this` is itself an synchronous action. It will have to no impact on performance @CertainPerformance

Comment: Does the second option take 4-times as long as the first option now? Because if so, then is'nt it better to use theh first option?

Comment: @IceRevenge No, the second code takes the same amount of time as the first, all requests are sent out in parallel, but the responses are parsed in serial - see how the `.then` is *inside* the `forEach`

Comment: Sorry, one more question: Would you say it is better to write repetetive code (like mine) or hard to undestand, but non-repetetive code (like yours)?

Comment: @IceRevenge Repetitive code makes itself harder to understand, I think - more code-text to read, more surface area for bugs. Maintainable code should be concise (not repetitive), but with liberal comments if what it's doing isn't sufficiently obvious at a glance. The code we see here is a bit strange in that respect because the results of the asynchronous calls don't trigger anything by themselves, they're only stored, which is pretty odd to do - usually, when a response comes back, you want to *do* something with it (like display on the page), rather than just store it in an object

Comment: @IceRevenge One option to make things more readable is to [extract till you drop](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop), if you're familiar with that sort of pattern

Answer (score 0):

To answer, No you shouldn't block other XHR or any I/O request which are not dependent on each other. I would have written your function like this;

```js
const getFavourites = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await Promise.resolve("Pizza");
    console.log("Favourite food: " + result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error getting food');
  }
  try {
    const result = await Promise.resolve("Monkey");
    console.log("Favourite animal: " + result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error getting animal');
  }
  try {
    const result = await Promise.resolve("Green");
    console.log("Favourite color: " + result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error getting color');
  }
  try {
    const result = await Promise.resolve("Water");
    console.log("Favourite liquid: " + result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error getting liquid');
  }
}

getFavourites();
```

This way every async functions will be called at once, and no async action will block the other action.

Comment: There is an excellent article that I would like to share as well along with my answer which I feel is really helpful https://medium.freecodecamp.org/avoiding-the-async-await-hell-c77a0fb71c4c

Comment: Depends on the diversity of the async actions that you are about to perform, if they are the same. You can have a generic method & pass arguments in a loop. Where the function is itself async/await

Comment: @IceRevenge Note that this implementation will wait for all requests in *serial*, not in parallel. Eg. if each API call takes 400ms, and there are 4 requests to make, this will take 1600 ms to complete, rather than 400ms.

Answer (score -3):

<s>To create a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) you need to call new Promise((resolve, reject) => { return "Pizza"; })</s>

You're doing it the right way

If you want you can shorten the code by using an array (and its functions like `map`, etc...), but it won't improve its performance

Comment: _"To create a `Promise` you need to call `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { return "Pizza"; })`"_?

Comment: Works for the dummied-up code, but pretty sure OP's real code looks different. (also, no need for the `Promise` constructor here)

Comment: yeah if you want a promise of a pizza I can't think of a better way

Comment: See OP's `Promise.resolve` - it's much better than `new Promise(...`

Comment: Have a question... Are you sure you can return "Pizza"? I thought you always had to resolve("Pizza"). Real code is about to be provided...

Comment: @CertainPerformance is right. You can create a promise just by calling `Promise.resolve`, editing my answer

Comment: Ok I guess using an Array makes half of the code less repetetive but what about the other part?